# Using filter to iterate over a list

Tags: list, loops, filter, lambda

So I have been asked to use the `filter()` function to iterate a function over a list so that only the positive values are returned in the list once the function is applied.
So far I have this:

```
def positive_place(f, xs)
    ans = filter(lambda x: f(x) > 0, xs)
    return ans
```

I have been asked specifically not to use `for` loops (even though I would prefer to). I'm not too familiar with `filter()` and would greatly appreciate if someone can tell me where I've gone wrong. The function above simply returns the positive values in the list I provided.

Comment: What have you defined the function `f` which you are passing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function is proper. But there are a few errors:

- The function definition is wrong. It should include a `:` in the end. Like  `def positive_place(f, xs):`
- If you are using Python 3, It return a filter object. So you will have to cast it to a list. Like  `return list(ans)`

Your program will look like

```
def positive_place(f, xs):    
    ans = filter(lambda x: f(x) > 0, xs)
    return list(ans)
```